# Transaction error while installing php-pear on centos 6

Tags: php, pear, centos6, pecl

While i tried to install php-pear

```
yum install php-pear
```

i am getting "Transaction Check Error". Server is Centos 6 with php 5.6.25. All Apache, PHP, Mysql was directly created via latest Cpanel installation.

I tried to install pecl, but before i tried php-pear - getting an error. Here is the full report:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 85.13.201.2
 * base: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
 * extras: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
 * updates: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli >= 5.1.0-1 for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-5.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package          Arch           Version                  Repository       Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php-pear         noarch         1:1.9.4-5.el6            base            393 k
Installing for dependencies:
 php-cli          x86_64         5.3.3-48.el6_8           updates         2.2 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 2.6 M
Installed size: 8.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): php-cli-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64.rpm                 | 2.2 MB     00:00
(2/2): php-pear-1.9.4-5.el6.noarch.rpm                   | 393 kB     00:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            28 MB/s | 2.6 MB     00:00
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-0.0.6-5.5.1.cpanel.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Can anyone help me out, installing php-pear.

Comment: This is a cpanel issue (you probably need to find the right package name)